# How do I iterate through a static map in C++

Tags: c++, for-loop, stdmap

I seem to not be able to iterate through a static map, also can't seem to find a question to this. Maybe I am doing it wrong and it shouldn't matter if the map is static or not but here it goes.

I have a static map = `static std::map<std::string, Texture>* s_textureMap;`
(Texture is just a custom class I made)

I tried two different loops:

```
for (auto it = s_textureMap.begin(); it != s_textureMap.end(); it++)
    {
        std::cout << it->first  // string (key)
    }
```

or

```
for (auto const& str : m_programMap)
{
    std::cout << it->first  // string (key)
}
```

For the first loop I get error messages saying "initialize map at the very start of the app" and "expression must have class type"

For the second loop I get error messages saying "initialize map at the very start of the app" and "this ranged based 'for' statement requires a suitable "begin" function and none was found.

I have tried to look up this errors but can't seem to help me.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: If you have a pointer to a map, you have to dereference that pointer which you're not doing...

Comment: Please check the declaration.  And a static variable should in initialized somewhere initially.  I think that is missed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have isn't a static map, it's a static pointer to a map. Hence, you need to use the `->` dereferencing operator instead of `.`.

```
for (auto it = s_textureMap->begin(); it != s_textureMap->end(); it++)
{
    std::cout << it->first;  // string (key)
}
```

Alternatively, you can also use the latter loop by dereferencing `m_programMap` with `*`. (Assuming `m_programMap` is also a pointer to a map, it's not clear from what you've shown.)

```
for (auto const& str : *m_programMap)
{
    std::cout << it->first;  // string (key)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that is what you want to do, but your static map is declared as a pointer, I try with something like static `std::map<std::string, TextureMap> s_textureMap;` and it worked just fine.

Alternatively you could also do `s_textureMap->begin()` instead of `s_textureMap.begin()`, again, supposing that you actually want to use a static pointer.